External display not working after upgrading to ubuntu 24.04
I recently upgraded to ubuntu 24.04.1 from 22.04 and now my external display monitors are not working. They are connected through Thinkpad Hybrid usb-c to usb-a dock (40af). The keyboard and mouse that are connected through the dock are working, so its not an issue with the dock or the usb-c port. Also the monitors work when connected to the laptop directly through hdmi, meaning they are also fine individually.
I also tried to upgrade all drivers and also the displylink driver individually but that also does not solve the problem. I am not sure what else to try. Please suggest how to solve this.

USB-C (USB 3.2) can be twice as fast as USB-A  (USB 3.1) in its maximum configuration, however if you're using older versions like USB-A 2.0 (480 Mbps) vs. USB-C (20 Gbps), USB-C would be about 40 times faster. Use a USB-C port on your laptop to connect the dock. Check that USB-C features are enabled in your laptop's UEFI settings. Log out of your Ubuntu session and login again when selecting the Ubuntu on Xorg option.

Here’s the step-by-step process that fixed the issue for me:

Install the NVIDIA Driver open a terminal and run the following command
to :sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-560

Select the NVIDIA Driver in Software & Updates
Open Software & Updates from the application menu.
Go to the additional drivers tab.
Select the option:
"NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-560 (proprietary)".
Click apply changes and reboot your system.

Disable secure boot in BIOS:
During boot, enter your BIOS/UEFI settings
locate the secure boot option and disable it.
Save the changes and exit the BIOS.


This solution worked for me. Hopefully, it helps someone else facing the same issue!


USB-C (USB 3.2) can be twice as fast as USB-A (USB 3.1) in its maximum configuration, however if you're using older versions like USB-A 2.0 (480 Mbps) vs. USB-C (20 Gbps), USB-C would be about 40 times faster.

Use a USB-C port on your laptop to connect the dock.

Check that USB-C features are enabled in your laptop's UEFI settings.

Log out of your Ubuntu session and login again when selecting the Ubuntu on Xorg option.



My setup also includes 2x DisplayPort with a Samsung and Dell monitor, both via a i-tec docking station. It all worked fine on Ubuntu 22.04 for which I had to install a custum displaylink driver, see i.e. https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/1944022-how-to-install-displaylink-software-on-ubuntu-20-0
After upgrading to 24.04 the setup stopped working in detecting the external displays. Charging, audio and stuff through the docking station is still working, so I suppose its a driver issue. The driver also up to date, i.e. sudo apt install displaylink-driver shows me displaylink-driver is already the newest version (6.1.0-17).
Not sure where to look for, it seems a rather rare use case and not solved, yet.
